# Querying the collection and documents based on the value length in Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

suppose my DB gives me a query result as:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5c99d76a32aacf180485c3b3'),
 'text': 'ILLUSTRATION : 1\nFind the quotient and remainder q and r for the pairs of positive integers given below:\n(i) 23,4\n(ii) 81,3\n(iii) 12,5\nUTION.\n',
 'text2': '',
 'parent': None,
 'repost': 3,
 'time': datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 9, 16, 5, 27, 838000)}
```

I want to get the first 1000 documents where either the length of `text` or length of `text2` is >=5:

I can do this via Python but it'll be foolish thing to do:

```
objects = []
i = 0
for obj in db.essays.find():
    if len(obj['text']>=5) or len(obj['text2']>=5):
        objects.append(obj)
        i+=1
    if i==1000:
        break
```

I know it is so foolish.

I can use `limit(1000)` if I have the exact matches but I do not how to get documents based on value length.

**EDIT**:
Somehow I managed to do a **PATCH** as:

```
{ "$or":[{"$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$text" }, 5 ]}},
                                     {"$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$text2" }, 5 ]}},
                                    {"$expr": { "$gt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$text3" }, 5 ]}},
                                     ]}
```

But when I use the `AND` operation to get documents when all of the texts are less than 3 in length, it throws an error:

```
{ "$and":[{"$expr": { "$lt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$text" }, 5 ]}},
                                     {"$expr": { "$lt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$text2" }, 5 ]}},
                                    {"$expr": { "$lt": [ { "$strLenCP": "$text3" }, 5 ]}},
                                     ]}
```

it works with `limit(2)` but fails with >2 and throws an error as:

```
`OperationFailure: $strLenCP requires a string argument, found: null`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a pipeline with [strLenCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$or": [
          {
            "$gte": [
              {
                "$strLenCP": {
                  "$ifNull": [
                    "$text",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              },
              5
            ]
          },
          {
            "$gte": [
              {
                "$strLenCP": {
                  "$ifNull": [
                    "$text2",
                    ""
                  ]
                }
              },
              5
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1000
  }
])
```

However if you really care above performance the best way would be to preprocess that information:

```
{
'_id': ObjectId('5c99d76a32aacf180485c3b3'),
 'text': 'ILLUSTRATION : 1\nFind the quotient and remainder q and r for the pairs of positive integers given below:\n(i) 23,4\n(ii) 81,3\n(iii) 12,5\nUTION.\n',
 'text2': '',
 'parent': None,
 'repost': 3,
 'time': datetime.datetime(2010, 5, 9, 16, 5, 27, 838000),
  'text_len': 100,
  "text2_len": 0
}
```

So now a simple query would suffice:

```
db.essays.find({"$or": [{"text_len": {"$gte": 5}}, {"text2_len": {"$gte": 5}}]}).limit(1000)
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Qoffh2BJTUb)

Comment: Could you please look at the edit and let me know about the error?

Comment: It means you have a document with either `text` or `text2` fields not having a string value (could also be missing), I edited my answer to use `$ifNull` to avoid an error.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `$strLenCP` Aggregation Pipeline.

Here is a sample code illustration:

```
objects = []

for obj in db.essays.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "text1Len": {
                "$strLenCP": "$text"
            },
            "text2Len": {
                "$strLenCP": "$text2"
            },
            "docRoot": "$$ROOT",
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "$or": [
                {"text1Len": {"$gte": 5}},
                {"text2Len": {"$gte": 5}},
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$limit": 1000
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": "$docRoot"
        }
    },
]):
    objects.append(obj)
```

Comment: It throws an error when I use it with `$lt` .Could you please take a look at the edit.